# A simple javascript for translating two columns of words

Tags: javascript

I have the base of words like:

```
var words = [
["english_word1","german_word1"],
["english_word2","german_word2"],
["english_word3","german_word3"]
];
```

and I need a simple javascript for translating the words in both directions i.e. english -> german and german -> english. Something like:

```
<textarea id="source" onkeyup="translate();"></textarea>
<div id="result"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
function translate() {
 var source = document.getElementById('source').value;
 ... ???
 document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = result;
}
</script>
```

Without changing the base

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this code

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script>

            var words = [
                ["english_word1","german_word1"],
                ["english_word2","german_word2"],
                ["english_word3","german_word3"]
            ];

            function getlang(){
                var select = document.getElementById("language");
                return select.options[select.selectedIndex].value*1;
            }
            function search(keyword){
                for(var x = 0; x < words.length; x++){
                    var lang = getlang()
                    if(words[x][lang] == keyword) return words[x][(lang+1) % 2]
                }
                return false
            }
            function update(e){
                var source = document.getElementById('source').value;
                result = search(source);
                if(result !== false)
                    document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = result;
            }
            document.addEventListener("input",function(e){
                if(e.target.id == "source"){
                    update()
                }
            });
            document.addEventListener("change",function(e){
                if(e.target.id == "language"){
                    update()
                }
            });

        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <textarea id = "source"></textarea>
        <select id = "language">
            <option value = 0>English -> German</option>
            <option value = 1>German -> English</option>
        </select>
        <div id = "result"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: There is some reason to use the current data structure. For the first way, how should I call the functions of javascript: like `<textarea onkeyup="search();translate();"></textarea>` ?

Comment: oninput event would be better : <textarea oninput="translate()"></textarea>

Comment: I meant how should I call _both_ functions including `function search(keyword,language)` ? And where can I get `keyword` and `language` from ?

Comment: the translate function will call search to get the result